# DexClassloader run error on Android5.0

Tags: dexclassloader

Before Android5.0，I use DexClassloader load plugin dynamiclly，code like this：

```
DexClassLoader localDexClassLoader = new DexClassLoader(pluginSrcJarDir,cont.getDir("dex", 0).getAbsolutePath(), null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());

Class<?> pluginClass = localDexClassLoader.loadClass(className);  //error here
```

but on Android5.0 here is the error：

> 04-03 05:51:42.743: W/(1462): Zip: 792 extraneous bytes at the end of
>   the central directory 04-03 05:51:42.749: W/System.err(1462):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.garfield.item0.system.plugin01.AckGetIntroduce" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/data/com.garfield/cache/1428040302214.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] 04-03 05:51:42.811: W/System.err(1462):     Suppressed:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to open zip archive
>   '/data/data/com.garfield/cache/1428040302214.jar' 04-03 05:51:42.820:
>   W/System.err(1462):       at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method) 04-03
>   05:51:42.820: W/System.err(1462):         at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295) 04-03
>   05:51:42.821: W/System.err(1462):         at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:111) 04-03 05:51:42.821:
>   W/System.err(1462):       at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:151) 04-03 05:51:42.821:
>   W/System.err(1462):       at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:265)

why？please help me！before 5.0 it is ok。what happened on 5.0！

Answer (score 0):

From Android 5.0 on, the `JVM` on which Android runs on is `ART` but not `Dalvik` anymore. And look at your logcat trace:

```
dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile
```

your codes still tried to run `Dalvik` things.